# IsHandledCreated is set to false but during runtime it is set to true?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

**Hi,**

I have the following code that is runned during Application.Exit :

```
            if (InvokeRequired && this.IsHandleCreated)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => EndUpdate(Caller)));
                return;
            }
```

This throws the exception : **Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created** but only when application is exeting.

The strange part is that when debugger breaks for the error I can see that both InvokeRequired and IsHandledCreated is set to false so im not sure how it manage to get to the internal code(this.Invoke)?

In this case I just want to close the application without any exceptions.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the if statement and see what the values are before it errors.

Comment: @saj > I have never heard of a if that goes wrong so I supose that when it is checking the InvokeRequired and the IsHandleCreated it gets True/True but then another thread changes this right before Invoke is runned. Maby I could implement the check for IsHandleCreated within the Invoke method but its possible that this will result in the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking conditions that way is not thread-safe.
Firstly, you can hit the race condition when threads are switched between *if* operator and call to **Invoke**. In other cases i would recommend you put some synchronization here, but it's impossible to get inside framework code.

Also, **Invoke** puts query into the UI message queue and then UI thread extracts it from the queue and executes. Meanwhile, Invoke waits till UI thread finish executing this query using **Form.Handle**.
So make sure you don't have calls to **Form.Close**() inside **EndUpdate** method, that can lead to exception while waiting.

I just recommend you to put **EndUpdate**() call inside **Form.OnClosing**() override. That would be thread safe and **Handle** is guaranteed to exist.